# Facebook Unity SDK - get list of friends which use the application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.3 (building an Andorid player) and running into an issue trying to get a list of the friends which use the application. Have found various examples which use fql for that purpose, e.g "'/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'", but using the last in FB.API ended up with "400 Bad Request" error.
Any ideas?
10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, manage to find the solution. The problem was using FQL from JavaScript documentation example as is. The following code does the work:

var fqlQuery = "/fql?q=" + WWW.EscapeURL("SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1");
FB.API(fqlQuery, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetFbFriendsCallback);

The *GetFbFriendsCallback* code can be found in Smash Friends sample application provided with SDK.